# Missing implementation files in Salesforce IOS SDK

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, sdk

I created a ios project by running forceios create and only can see header files in its installed plugins like SalesforceSDKManager.h and SFUserAccountIdentity.h.  However, if I download the ios SDK sample project, which is https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS. I can see all the implementations for those headers. Can anyone tell me why? I do need to customise something in SalesforceSDKManager.m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your project with `forceios`, it will install the SDK as a [static library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html), so only certain headers are exported publicly and the implementations are private. If you want to view or edit the implementation, you should install the SDK as described in the [development repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS).

Comment: ok. That sounds like accessing implementations is blocked. Thanks Jonathan . Also, if you know, if installed from development repo, where to add podfile? I tried to add it into one of sample project and the entire project failed to compile and says "<SalesforceHybridSDK/SFHybridViewController.h>". However, if I remove the podfile, it complies.

Comment: It's not that the implementation is 'blocked' in a static library, it is precompiled and included as a binary. The podfile should go in the same folder as your `.xcodeproj` and should not added to the project.

Comment: Also if you want to make edits to the library, I would not recommend installing it as a pod since your edits will be overwritten the next time you `pod install`.

Comment: I put into the same folder as .xcodeproj but it's causing this issue.

Comment: Hard to say more without a more specific error message. You might consider another question for that.

Comment: Right. I do need to edit the library. if not using pod, is there any easier way to add into library than just doing by manual?

Comment: Yes. I will put it into anther question.